# how to check what port django used on a running server? `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:<port>`, or through apache/nginx

Tags: django, ubuntu, port

I need to troubleshot a django app which already running in a server. I'd like to access the APP URL `IP:PORT` but I don't know what port former developer used to run it. Eg: `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:<port>`

Is there a possibility to check out this used port with something like

```
netstat -ano | grep ...
```

`netstat -ano | grep runserver` doesn't provide anything.

If it doesn't use `runserver`, how should I check (apache/nginx)?

Comment: Don't you already know the URL (IP + port) of the app if you can access it? Or can you not even access the app?

Comment: I cannot even access the app, it's not a simple web app.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the server was started using "runserver"? If a webserver like apache or nginx was used, then you need to look for those process names.

---

If "runserver" was used:

**Option 1:** `netstat` and `grep` for "python" instead of "runserver" (see [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/278455/865083)):

```
$ sudo netstat -peanut | grep python
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       3645959    28500/python        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37004         127.0.0.1:39989         ESTABLISHED 1000       3041068    22188/python        
$
```

**Option 2:** `ps` and `grep` for "runserver":

```
$ ps -aux | grep runserver
ralf     28500  2.2  0.4 309672 74184 tty2     Sl+  14:11   0:14 /home/ralf/.venv/bin/python /home/ralf/manage.py runserver
ralf     29199  0.0  0.0  21532  1000 pts/0    S+   14:22   0:00 grep --color=auto runserver
$
```

Comment: Hum, the `ps -aux | grep runserver` should do the trick, but it doesn't give any output. I assume then the app is served through apach or nginx. Thnx